# Eclipse plugin creates information dialog error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have made menu item in project explorer, where the user can right click on any java project and then select "pop menu" from the context menu. The problem is the when I click on that it gives me a information dialog box that says "the chosen operation is not currently available" it should actually show the hello world dialog box but it doesn't. Can anybody see the problem in my code:

This for plugin.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
     <objectContribution
        id ="org.eclipse.ui.examples.project"
        objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
        <action id="org.eclipse.ui.examples.project.action1"
            label = "popup menu"
            menubarPath = "additions"
            class = "org.eclipse.examples.HelloWorld"
            definitonId = "org.eclipse.ui.examples.project.action1"
            enablesFor ="1">
        </action>
     </objectContribution>
```

This is the code for helloworld.java file:

```
public class HelloWorld implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate {
private IWorkbenchWindow window;
public void run(IAction action) {
    MessageDialog.openInformation(
        window.getShell(),
        "HelloWorld",
        "Hello, Eclipse world");
}.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to specify

```
 adaptable="true"
```

as part of the `objectContribution`:

```
 <objectContribution
    id ="org.eclipse.ui.examples.project"
    objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"
    adaptable="true">
```

This is because most user interface objects do not implement the workspace objects such as `IProject` directly. Instead they provide an 'adapter' to convert to the object, you must specify the 'adaptable' attribute to make the menu code look for the adapter.

Note: The `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` is now deprecated.

Comment: I tired that as well but it still gives me the same error. I also added extended the interface for IObjectActionDelegate and still doesn't seem to work. I don't what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks that actually worked and also I forgot to write the class name in class path.